# Split array in magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an array like this

```
on;tracking34567;1;ABC;2019-08-13;on;tracking123;1;BCD;2019-08-13;on;123456test;1;USA;2019-08-13;
```

How to split it like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => on
    [1] => tracking34567
    [2] => 1
    [3] => ABC
    [4] => 2019-08-13
)
Array
(
    [0] => on
    [1] => tracking123
    [2] => 1
    [3] => BCD
    [4] => 2019-08-13
)
Array
(
    [0] => on
    [1] => 123456test
    [2] => 1
    [3] => USA
    [4] => 2019-08-13
)
```

Please help me

**UPDATE**

I tryed but it show

```
public function indexAction()
      {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParam("values");
        $temp = explode(";",$string);
        $i = 0;
        $result = array();
        foreach($temp as $v){
            if($v == "on"){
                $i++;
            }
            $result[$i][] = $v;
        }
        print_r($result);exit;
          // var_dump($data);exit;
      }
```

[image]

UPDATE

It work fine, but if i need array like this, how to change it?

```
Array
(
    [a] => on
    [b] => tracking34567
    [c] => 1
    [d] => ABC
    [e] => 2019-08-13
)
Array
(
    [a] => on
    [b] => tracking123
    [c] => 1
    [d] => BCD
    [e] => 2019-08-13
)
Array
(
    [a] => on
    [b] => 123456test
    [c] => 1
    [d] => USA
    [e] => 2019-08-13
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to convert whole string in array

```
<?php
$string = 'on;tracking34567;1;ABC;2019-08-13;on;tracking123;1;BCD;2019-08-13;on;123456test;1;USA;2019-08-13;';
$temp = explode(";",$string);
```

Now use this temp array to create your new array

```
$i = -1;
$k = 0;
$result = array();
$alpha = range('a','z');
foreach($temp as $v){
    if($v == "on"){
        $i++;
        $k=0;
    }
    $result[$i][$alpha[$k]] = $v;
    $k++;
}
```

You will have your result in `$result`

Comment: change `$data = $this->getRequest()->getParam("values");` to `$string = $this->getRequest()->getParam("values");` this will fix your issue

Comment: It work fine, can you help me a problem? please check update question again

Comment: sure, let me try

Comment: Thank you very much <3 have a nice day

Comment: Good to hear that you have resolved it. +1 for answer acceptance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$string = 'on;tracking34567;1;ABC;2019-08-13;on;tracking123;1;BCD;2019-08-13;on;123456test;1;USA;2019-08-13;';
$temp = explode(";",$string);
$i = 0;
$result = array();
$j = 'a';
foreach($temp as $v){

    if($v == "on"){
        $i++;
        $j = 'a';
    }else
    {
        $j++;
    }
    $result[$i][$j] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below:

```
$arrayStr = "on;tracking34567;1;ABC;2019-08-13;on;tracking123;1;BCD;2019-08-13;on;123456test;1;USA;2019-08-13";
print_r (explode(";",$arrayStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this it will help you.

```
    <?php
    $string = 'on;tracking34567;1;ABC;2019-08-13;on;tracking123;1;BCD;2019-08-13;on;123456test;1;USA;2019-08-13;';

    $arr = explode(';',$string);

    $result = array_chunk($arr, 5);

    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($result);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$string = "on;tracking34567;1;ABC;2019-08-13;on;tracking123;1;BCD;2019-08-13;on;123456test;1;USA;2019-08-13";
$arr = explode("on",$string);

for($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i++ ){
    $arr[$i] = "on".$arr[$i];
    $arr[$i] = explode(";",$arr[$i]);
}


$arr = array_filter($arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If values in your string always comes in the same format and there are always five element in the string, then you can do it in a much better and simpler way, rather then using loops.

You can use php in-built functions and achieve it.
Here have a look at the code.

```
<?php
$text = "on;tracking34567;1;ABC;2019-08-13;on;tracking123;1;BCD;2019-08-13;on;123456test;1;USA;2019-08-13;";
$exploded_string = explode(';', $text);
$final_array = array_chunk($exploded_string, 5);
print_r($final_array);
?>
```

Hope this helps.Thanks